# "Create HTML Table" CSS Style to Format SP List as Single-Column layout

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, html, microsoft-flow, table

I am using a SharePoint List to store News Clips related to my company. I have created a flow to auto-send them to a distro list, and achieved a clean table, but wish to create an email where the fields are stacked vertically with space between each row. Please help.

**OUTPUT (Current)**

| Title | Author | Publication |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sun shines daily | Sam Snuffy | Duh News |
| Politics actually corrupt | Wendy Whitfield | Wow World News |

**OUTPUT (Desired)**

Sun Shines Daily
Sam Snuffy
Duh News

Politics actually corrupt
Wendy Whitfield
Wow World News

Etc.